# How do I use htaccess to redirect to subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to use `.htaccess` to use subdomains on a website but have little to no experience with .htaccess. I have the following in my `.htaccess` file but it doesn't work:
Most of this I copied from other peoples suggestions. What I want is to enter **Family.mysitehere.org** and have it go to **mysitehere.org/Family**
Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code? Many thanks in advance.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php

AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule wmail$ http://webmail.x7hosting.com [R,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}<>%{REQUEST_URI} ^([^.]+)\.mysitehere\.org(:80)?<>/([^/]*) [NC]

RewriteCond %1<>%3 !^(.*)<>\1$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /%1/$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404missing.php
```

Answer (score 0):

> `What I want is to enter Family.mysitehere.org and have it go to mysitehere.org/Family`

Use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(Family)\.(mysitehere\.org)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```